# Does JSDoc recognize member assignment

Tags: node.js, jsdoc, commonjs

I think it is common practice to separate public and private members like this:

```
// lib/index.js
exports.publicFunc = require('./private').internalFunc;

// lib/private.js
/**
 * My private function
 *
 * @param {string} foo some foo
 * @return {number} bar value
 */
exports.internalFunc = foo => 42;
```

With this, I run `jsdoc lib/index.js` but get nothing. If I run `jsdoc lib` then `internalFunc` is also displayed, which I would like to hide. Is JSDoc designed for such case? If so, how can I generate the JSDoc for a package like this? I don't want to repeat the documentations, so I won't copy those documentation to `lib/index.js`.

Comment: I'm trying out [`@borrow`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-borrows.html).

Comment: No, `@borrow` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want the resultant JSDoc to show. Given your example, do you expect after running: `jsdoc lib`  for the final JSDoc to: **1.** Be empty (i.e. show nothing)? **2.** Or `publicFunc` to reflect details of `internalFunc` without actually displaying `internalFunc` **3.** Or something else?

Comment: @RobC I want option 2, because `publicFunc` is actually `internalFunc`. They refer to the same JavaScript Object, AFAIK.